# Java byte Insert value error string to byte

Tags: java, types, type-conversion, byte, arrays

I have class that have one member myByte as follows.

```
public class ByteClass {
    private Byte myByte;
    public Byte getMyByte() {
        return myByte;
    }
    public void setMyByte(Byte myByte) {
        this.myByte = myByte;
    }
}
```

I have string value which is **FF** and I need to assign it to the class member,
how should I do that since when I try it ass follows I got error in the compile time

*Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[] to byte* I understand that I cant use Array of byte for the string but I have tried to do that in several of ways without any success .any Idea how can I set the value FF to the class ?

```
public class ByteHanlder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "FF";
        byte temp = str.getBytes();
        Byte write_data = new Byte(temp);
        ByteClass byteClass = new ByteClass();
        byteClass.setMyByte(temp);
        System.out.println(byteClass.getMyByte());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really do just want to store a byte, you can use:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("FF", 16); 
x.setMyByte((byte) value);
```

Now that will give you a value of -1 if you look at it in the debugger - but that's just because bytes are signed, as other answerers have noted. If you want to see the *unsigned* value at any time, you can just use:

```
// Only keep the bottom 8 bits within a 32-bit integer, which ends up
// treating the original byte as an unsigned value.
int value = x.getMyByte() & 0xff;
```

You can still just *store* a byte - and then interpret it in an unsigned way rather than a signed way. If you really just want to store a single byte - 8 bits - I suggest you *don't* change to using a `short`.

Having said all this, it's somewhat odd to need a mutable wrapper type just for a byte... perhaps you could give us more context as to why you want this, and we may be able to suggest cleaner alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Your String "FF" seems to be a hex value, right? So you actually want to convert it to the byte value of 255.

You can use a method like described here to convert a hex string to a byte array: [Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java).

In your case, you could adapt that method to expect a 2-letter string and return a single byte instead of a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

`String.getBytes` return a bytearray so you can not assign a bytearray to a byte.

If you want to set FF hex value then you could use

```
setMyByte((byte)0xff);
```

But there is still a problem 0xff is of 2 byte size but byte type is of 1 byte. In that case you can use short instead of byte

Comment: SO i need to define the member as byte array?and I should convert it from FF to 0Xff?

Comment: There are many options.. you can set the member as byte array and set the byte array easily. Or you can declare the member as short